# Understanding cryptography practically

Tags: cryptography

So I am interested in computer security, cryptography and security protocols. Thing is, everything I read is about theoretical usage of protocols, but how do those things work in real world?

Is there a book or paper that I can read and understand how everything works practically. Like how everything is implemented programically, not just on paper? I am not talking about implementation of cipher itself programically, but how everything works together? Let's say I login to internet banking and lot's of stuff happen automatically regarding encryption, sessions, etc., but how can I see real world example of what is happening there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are private key cryptography and public key cryptography, and where are they useful?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5402/what-are-private-key-cryptography-and-public-key-cryptography-and-where-are-the)

Comment: Several sites available that walk you through the practical steps. Wiki, YouTube, etc.

Comment: I've voted to close your question as too broad, because every real-world application which uses cryptography in some way does it completely different. Narrowing your question down to one specific use-case would make it more answerable. When you are interested in how encryption of a web-based online banking session works (https), [the wikipedia article about TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) might help you.

Comment: Guys, it's all theoretical, especially on youtube and wiki. I am looking for practical imeplementations and explanation on how everything works together with examples. Schroeder, that link does not contain what I am looking whatsoever.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you could try [OpenCourseWare](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-857-network-and-computer-security-fall-2003/).  It appears there is a few examples at the end of the book they use.

Comment: @user1880405 The problem you might be facing is that in practice, programmers use libraries to initiate secure connections. Not much to see unless you pick apart the libraries. You have to know the theory to understand what the libraries are doing. Packet is encrypted at one end, and decrypted at the other. Specific implementation is up to the language that calls the specific libraries to do that.

Comment: @schroeder Maybe that's the case, but if I work in a company and I need to implement different security measures, I am supposed to know how to do everything, not just how in theory everything works.

Comment: @user1880405 I understand that, but your question, then, is too broad. Are you looking for implementation in PHP? C? Server level? SSH? 'Everything' is not practical.

Comment: @schroeder I don't know. Everything I read is on theoretical side of things, so this question popped in my head.

Answer (score 1):

The book you are after is:

[Cryptography and Network Security: Principles and Practice](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Cryptography-Network-Security-Principles-Practice/dp/0273793357/ref=sr_1_11?ie=UTF8&qid=1401385268&sr=8-11&keywords=network%20security)

This book contains all the information you need to understand the use of cryptography in practical protocol applications.

Comment: Thank you. Can I still read 5th edition for same information, which is available online for free, or 6th provides much better up do date info?